# Excel filters doesnt show after import to SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

My excel file has 30 filters and efter I import it to SharePoint Online the file only shows around 10 filters only. Why is this? Is there any workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multi-line text columns in the excel you are importing?

If YES, those columns cannot be filtered in view, by default.

Also, as you mentioned filter was not showing up after importing to SharePoint, Please review the data type of the columns after importing to SharePoint whether it is changing to multi-line text.

Hope this helps!